# How can i change indices of a matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, indexing

My problem is i want to assign some numbers to indices of a matrix. For example if I remove first row and first column of a matrix, then in remaining matrix 3th row and 4 column would actually be 4th row and 5th column in the first place.

I can do it with Array1(Array2) , however my code will have many seperate recursions so it is frustrating to keep track of everything. So, is there an once and for all way to map original 1..n indices to remaining matrix even after I remove rows and columnsth

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, there isn't. You'll have to keep track of the indices yourself in a separate array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this as per beaker's suggestion

```
originalMatrix = magic(4)
dimension = size(originalMatrix)
indexMatrix = zeros(dimension(1), dimension(2))

for i = 1:numel(indexMatrix)
    indexMatrix(i) = i
end
```

and remove the required row and column from `indexMatrix`.